# Python: what happens when code is executed, what's the logic?

Tags: python, function

I'm a beginner at Python and I really need help understanding how this code works. I need to write down what this program does - what gets printed and how the values of variables change as the program does it's thing. 
I know functions need to be called and I know how loops work, but what confuses me about this is the last line. If it was just print(funk2(a, a)), the program would print 5, 5, if, return and 5. But what happens if it's an argument?

```
    def funk2(x, y):
        print(x)
        print(y)
        while x > 1:
            if y == 2 or not x > y:
                x -= 4
                print("if")
            elif y != 4:
                print("return")
                return y
            else:
                print("else")
                x += 2
        print("return")
        return 5
    a = 5
    print(funk2(a + 1, funk2(a, a)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down the last line only:

```
funk2(a + 1, funk2(a, a))
```

It'll first evaluate `funk2(a, a)` which in turn returns a value (let's say it corresponds to `x`).
Then it'll evaluate `a+1` where `a = 5`, so `6`.

And then, finally it'll call the function `funk2`:

```
funk2(6, x)
```

That's it!

You could also have written the last line like this:

```
b = a + 1
c = funk2(a, a)
print(funk2(b, c))
```

Comment: That totally makes sense, I get it now. Thank you so much! (It was a typo, both are funk2.)